# Textarea's resize grabber not hidden by floating div on Chrome/Firefox

Tags: css

I'm having a problem with the resize grabber of a textarea poking through the background of an overlapping div.  This div is trying to show content like a pop-up dialog, so it uses an absolute position to sit on top of the text area.  However, that affect is ruined by the resize grabber not being properly occluded by div.

Any ideas?

This jsfiddle reproduces the problem for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/czerwin/bdWLw/1/

HTML:

```
HTML:

<div>
    <textarea>This is the text in the text area. For some reason, the resize grabber is not properly hidden by a div positioned over it.
     </textarea>
</div>
<div class="floater">Here is the overlay div. It should occlude a portion of the text area.
</div>


CSS:
.floater {
   position: absolute;
   left: 100px;
   top: 30px;
   background: white;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

This is happening on Chrome 26.0.1410.43 on Mac 10.8.3.  I also tried it on Safari with the same outcome.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead... `textarea { resize: none; }`

Comment: Sorry, should have been clear.  I would like to keep the resize grabber on the text area because it is useful when I'm not showing the pop-up.  I have explored techniques where I add in "resize:none" to the textarea when I popup the second div, but that looks odd when the pop up would not have occluded the grabber.  I'm hoping that there's a better solution than that manual hackery.

Comment: Tried messing with z-index?

Comment: Yup, I tried setting the z-index to something very high, use relative positioning on all other elements, and nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Looking at your jsfiddle, I can't replicate the same problem.  I am using Chrome V25, I have not updated to 26 yet, I will do so and re-test and edit this post.

Comment: I had my coworker try it on Chrome 25, and he can't repro it either.  I tried Firefox version 19 on my computer, and that didn't repro it either.  So, right now, Chrome 26 and Safari 6.0.3 on my computer repro it.  Sigh.